# Using File Event notification in Solaris 9 , 10 and 11 when a directory/file is changed

Tags: events, solaris, ports

I read the Solaris man pages but they are not very clear of how to use event notifications for directories. For example, If I add a new file into a directory, I would like to get some notification of that event( like inotify in linux).

Can you please give a sample code. I found this link: [blogs.oracle.com/praks/entry/file_events_notification](http://blogs.oracle.com/praks/entry/file_events_notification) which has what I need but it is for Solaris 11.

I found a library called Libev but it doesn't work for directory changes in Solaris. 
If you know any C or C++ based event library that would be great!

Any suggestion is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could use [FAM](http://techpubs.sgi.com/library/tpl/cgi-bin/getdoc.cgi?coll=0650&db=bks&fname=/SGI_Developer/books/IIDsktp_IG/sgi_html/ch08.html) (e.g. installed via [OpenCSW](http://www.opencsw.org/package/fam/)).